# why is the text not moving up?

Tags: html, css

Why is the text p not moving up ?
I have tried to move it with: bottom, margin-bottom, padding-bottom. It moves only when I remove the bluePoint1 `div.`

```css
.bluePoint1 {
  left: -12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 3.75rem;
  color: #5CABD1;
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluePoint1">&bull</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteur adipiscing elit, sed do elusmod tempor incididumt ut <br> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
```

Comment: bottom apply only to positioned element ... use margin-TOP to move it **down** and negative margin-TOP to move it **up**

Comment: Or remove the margin/ padding from the previous element...

Comment: It seems to me, that you want to have a custom unordered list. If I am right you should read this article https://css-tricks.com/ordered-lists-unicode-symbols/ and use <ul> instead of this <div> & <p> combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi add the following in you p tag in css:

```
margin-top: -20px;
```

The entire css will look like this:

```
.bluePoint1 {
              left: -12px;
              margin-right: 10px;
              font-size: 3.75rem;
              color: #5CABD1;
              }

p {
   font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-align: center;
   bottom: 1000px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `margin:0` to your `p` element

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/skffb305/4/)